# Using 'column -t' on macOS vs. CentOS

Tags: bash, macos, centos

I want to print some text in a pretty-printed table.
Take this example:

```
{
    echo -e "\tIP address:-1.2.3.4"
    echo -e "\tNetmask:-1.2.3.4"
    echo -e "\tGateway:-1.2.3.4"
    echo -e "\tDefault gateway:-1.2.3.4"
} | column -ts-
```

On macOS (10.14.4 for me), this prints just as I would expect:

```
    IP address:       1.2.3.4
    Netmask:          1.2.3.4
    Gateway:          1.2.3.4
    Default gateway:  1.2.3.4
```

However, on CentOS (tested on both 6 and 7), it is not so beautiful:

```
    IP address:   1.2.3.4
    Netmask:   1.2.3.4
    Gateway:   1.2.3.4
    Default gateway:   1.2.3.4
```

So my question is: is there a better way I should be doing this? At least for CentOS?

Bonus points if you can tell me *why* it works on macOS but not CentOS!

**Edit**:

My outputs (i.e. columns) can vary in length depending on some different factors, so I would prefer a solution where I do not have to manually specify the number of spaces to print to make it look pretty.

Comment: I think the issue is related to the terminal rather than the OS. If the terminal is programmed or configured to show tabs as four spaces, it will produce the second output.

Comment: @oguzismail, I get similar results even after setting my tab-stops using `tabs -n`, where `n` is some natural number. It is worth noting that macOS is my local OS (using Terminal) and I am connecting to the CentOS hosts over SSH.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `\t`s from the front of each echo string? You could always add `| sed 's/^/\t/'` after the `column` to add them back in if that helps.

Comment: @EdMorton, adding the tabs after the `column` command works! However, I could see how in different use-cases it might not be desirable to add tabs in front of **everything** output from the command block. Also, `sed` on Mac does not like the `\t` escape sequence. You have to use control-v, and then hit tab to insert a literal tab.

Comment: There's various workarounds like using 8 blanks to represent a tab in the original code and then replacing every set of 8 blanks with a tab in the output (assuming you like 8-char tabs). It's not perfect but probably adequate. You can also probably use `$'\t'` to get a literal tab char - `sed 's/ \{8\}/'$'\t''/'`

Comment: @EdMorton, this works on both platforms (shortened to a one-liner just for this comment): `echo -e "IP address:-1.2.3.4\nNetmask:-1.2.3.4\nGateway:-1.2.3.4\nDefault gateway:-1.2.3.4" | column -ts- | sed s/^/$'\t'/`.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` and `column` are good for hacking away at the command line.

Best practice pretty printing usually involves `printf`:

```
IPv4=('IP address:' 1.2.3.4 Netmask: 1.2.3.4 Gateway: 1.2.3.4 Default\ gateway: 1.2.3.4)
ip=; for ip in "${IPv4[@]}"; do ((${#ip} > max)) && max=${#ip}; done
printf "\t%-$((max+2))s%s\n" "${IPv4[@]}"
```

`\t%-18s%s\n` means "literal tab, string padded to 18 characters, string, newline". It contains two argument specifiers `%x`, which bash will recycle for all arguments.

Note: multi-word elements must be quoted or have their spaces escaped in order to be treated singularly

*edit:* added flexbile max length

Comment: This works. However, my output can vary in length, so I would prefer a solution where I don't have to manually specify/update the number of spaces to pad with. I will update my question to indicate this.

Comment: ez, added that feature